# What's the name for the act of importing and normalizing data from flat files?

Tags: import

There's a name for the act of importing and normalizing data from flat files but I can't remember what it is. I know there is one because I looked it up the other day. I believe it's a three-letter abbreviation that starts with an E. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the acronym you're looking for is ETL: Extract, Transform, Load.